# Uploading videos with the Media uploader

Tags: 7, files, media

I am trying to create a video gallery. I was originally trying to use the Media module with shadowbox to display them, but I have not been able to figure out how to get a thumbnail for the media. What I came up with was the Video module. The video module allows me to create a thumbnail, however I wanted an uploader similar to the media module one, which allows me to upload it, get it from the web, or use a video that is already in my library. Is there an ad-on module for Video that will allow me to upload videos like this?

Answer (score 1):

The video module is strictly for videos that your users upload. You need to configure the transcoding (ffmpeg on your server or use the external Zencoder service).
If you want to embed Youtube or Vimeo videos you can use [video embed field](http://drupal.org/project/video_embed_field) module.

I've combined the two to allow video uploads and video embeds. However I really prefer the video embed field since dealing your users uploading a ton of large video files isn't trivial.